# Qt: Specifying multiple connection types with QObject::connect

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qtcore, qt-signals

I wanted to know if it is possible to specify multiple connection types. For example, I want my connection type to be a queued connection and a unique connection. Is it possible to specify that in one statement ?

```
QObject::connect(ptrSender,SIGNAL(..),ptrReceiver,SLOT(...),Queued-and-unique)
```

**Update :**

Following the suggestion of the posters:

I tried using  `Qt::QueuedConnection | Qt::UniqueConnection` but I get

```
 `Error 1   error C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'int' to 'Qt::ConnectionType'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it possible to specify that in one statement ?

In theory, it seems to be possible for your scenario. At least, you can read the docs [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) about it.

> Qt::UniqueConnection  0x80    This is a flag that can be combined with any one of the above connection types, using a bitwise OR. When Qt::UniqueConnection is set, QObject::connect() will fail if the connection already exists (i.e. if the same signal is already connected to the same slot for the same pair of objects). This flag was introduced in Qt 4.6.

Based on the aforementioned documentation, you would write something like this:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication coreApplication(argc, argv);
    QObject::connect(&coreApplication, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), &coreApplication, SLOT(quit()), static_cast<Qt::ConnectionType>(Qt::QueuedConnection | Qt::UniqueConnection));
    return coreApplication.exec();
}
```

Comment: `Error 1 error C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'int' to 'Qt::ConnectionType' ` this is when I used `Qt::QueuedConnection | Qt::UniqueConnection`

Answer (score 10):

*It's possible*, but C++ prevents passing the OR in the way you're doing it.

The problem is that `connect` takes an argument of type `Qt::ConnectionType`. **Bitwise OR'ing two values from an enum produces a value of type `int`** (the enum values undergo *integer promotion* in order to apply the bitwise OR operator). This causes the compile error you're getting:

> cannot convert parameter 5 from 'int' to 'Qt::ConnectionType'

(Remember that in C++ integrals don't automatically convert into enums).

So the solution is casting back the result of the OR into the right type, and the right cast to use is `static_cast`:

```
static_cast<Qt::ConnectionType>(Qt::QueuedConnection | Qt::UniqueConnection)
```

---

Now you might ask "why didn't Qt authors think about this"? Well, the fact is that *`Qt::UniqueConnection` has been added in Qt 4.6*.

Before, `connect` only took a single enum value, not an OR combination of them. That's why `connect` has this signature:

```
connect(..., Qt::ConnectionType)
```

and not something like this:

```
connect(..., QFlags<Qt::ConnectionType>)
connect(..., int)
```

which instead would've allowed the OR. (Note that these latter two signatures also allow for things such as `Qt::DirectConnection | Qt::QueuedConnection`, which don't make sense).

Comment: actually `Qt::AutoCompatConnection` has a value of 3, which equals to `Qt::DirectConnection | Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible. Because `Qt::UniqueConnection` is a flag that can be combined with any one of other connection types, using a bitwise OR.

`QObject::connect(ptrSender,SIGNAL(..),ptrReceiver,SLOT(...), Qt::UniqueConnection | Qt::QueuedConnection);`

Check documentation: [connection type](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

In Qt v. 4.8 `Qt::UniqueConnection` also has value 0x80, which allows to combine it with other connection types.